# Performance of async in F# vs C# (is there a better way to write async { ... })

Tags: f#, async-await

FWIW I think that the issues detailed here just comes down to the c# compiler being smarter, and making an efficient state machine based model to handle async code, whereas the F# compiler creates a myriad of objects and function calls that are just generally less efficient.

Anyway, if I have the c# function below:

```cs
public async static Task<IReadOnlyList<T>> CSharpAsyncRead<T>(
         SqlCommand cmd,
         Func<SqlDataReader, T> createDatum)
{
    var result = new List<T>();
    var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();

    while (await reader.ReadAsync())
    {
        var datum = createDatum(reader);
        result.Add(datum);
    }

    return result.AsReadOnly();
}
```

And then convert this to F# as follows:

```
let fsharpAsyncRead1 (cmd:SqlCommand) createDatum = async {
    let! reader =
        Async.AwaitTask (cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync ())

    let rec readRows (results:ResizeArray<_>) = async {
        let! readAsyncResult = Async.AwaitTask (reader.ReadAsync ())
        if readAsyncResult then
            let datum = createDatum reader
            results.Add datum
            return! readRows results
        else
            return results.AsReadOnly() :> IReadOnlyList<_>
    }

    return! readRows (ResizeArray ())
}
```

Then I find that the performance of the f# code is significantly slower, and more CPU hungry, than the c# version. I was wondering if there better was to compose it. I tried removing the recursive function (which appeared a bit ugly with the no while! and no mutable let!s) as follows:

```
let fsharpAsyncRead2 (cmd:SqlCommand) createDatum = async {
    let result = ResizeArray () 

    let! reader =
        Async.AwaitTask (cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync ())

    let! moreData = Async.AwaitTask (reader.ReadAsync ())
    let mutable isMoreData = moreData
    while isMoreData do
        let datum = createDatum reader

        result.Add datum

        let! moreData = Async.AwaitTask (reader.ReadAsync ())
        isMoreData <- moreData

    return result.AsReadOnly() :> IReadOnlyList<_>
}
```

But the performance was basically the same.

As an example of the performance, when I was loading a bar of market data such as:

```
type OHLC = {
    Time  : DateTime
    Open  : float
    High  : float
    Low   : float
    Close : float
}
```

On my machine, the F# async version took ~ twice as long, and consumed ~ twice as much CPU resources for the whole time it ran - thus taking about 4x as many resources (i.e. internally it must be spinning up more threads?).

(Possibly it is somewhat dubious to be doing a read of such a trivial structure? I'm really just poking the machine to see what it does. In comparison to the non-async version (i.e. just straight Reads) the c# one completes in ~ same time, but consumes > twice as much CPU. i.e straight Read() consumes < 1/8 of the f# resources)

So my question is, as I doing the F# async the "right" way (this was my first attempted usage)?

(...and if I am, then do I just need to go and modify the compiler to add a state machine based implementation for compiled Asyncs... how hard could that be :-) )

Comment: Are you sure they both run with the same settings regarding bitness, optimization and such?

Comment: Have you looked at `hopac` (https://github.com/Hopac/Hopac)? it has significant lower CPU overhead than `Async` (and IIRC lower than `Task`) . FYI; I would personally not consider to use `Async` or `TPL` and so on when I need parallelism. If I am CPU bound I most likely can't affort the abstractions.

Comment: @FuleSnabel BTW, I did consider Hopac because it is indeed faster than `async{}`. But interop with C# (lack of) was a dealbreaker. `task{}` computation expression gives a way to use TPL (which is probably the most optimized piece of .NET) in F# idiomatic way.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Yes, the did have same bitness, optimizations, etc. (The c# code was just added as a reference, and I just swapped the calls). (Slightly off topic, but possibly interesting, fact here is that in 32-bit with gcServer=false, then the async c# version is faster than the direct non-async Read. This disappears though with 64-bit with gcServer=true. I can't remember other configurations timings.)

Comment: @FuleSnabel I remember reading about Hopac ages ago, but hadn't tried it, and had forgotten. Your reminder has acted to rekindle my interest. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

F#'s `Async` and TPL boundary (Async.AwaitTask/Async.StartAsTask) is the slowest thing. But in general, F# Async is slower itself and should be used for IO bound not CPU bound tasks. You may find this repo interesting: https://github.com/buybackoff/FSharpAsyncVsTPL

Basically, I benchmarked the two and also a task builder computation expression, that is originally from [FSharpx](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpx.Extras/blob/8f87218d67fba040ab419021dc36fdf2547c949f/src/FSharpx.Extras/ComputationExpressions/Monad.fs#L1001) project. Task builder is much faster when used together with TPL. I use this approach in my Spreads library - which is written in F# but leverages TPL. On [this line](https://github.com/Spreads/Spreads/blob/097460d8c682826aae30ee49f0c5a0b17f9c1bdb/src/Spreads.Collections/Common/Utils.fs#L153) is highly optimized bind of computation expression which effectively does the same thing as C#'s async/await behind the scenes. I benchmarked every use of `task{}` computation expression in the library and it is very fast (the gotcha is not to use for/while of computation expression, but recursion). Also, it makes the code interoperable with C#, while F#'s async cannot be consumed from C#.

Comment: I couldn't see any performance different with GetAwaiter(). Here is a gist of my tests - https://gist.github.com/manofstick/e0f1cbf14febf3666c06 - I tried 32/64-bit, with and without gcServer. (and I checked that the fast path m.IsCompleted wasn't being hit all the time)

Comment: ...and actually if you modify that gist to bump up the number of tasks created to be quite large (million), cut down their work load so they will be pretty quick, create the Tasks suspended, and then just Start() them just before the bind, then you find that the ContinueWith outperforms GetAwaiter version.

Comment: @PaulWestcott When I tested the difference wasn't big and was within the margin of error. Using AsyncTaskMethodBuilder instead of TaskCompletionSource was actually marginally slower (couple of percents), but I decided not to allocate additional objects if possible.

Comment: @PaulWestcott The logic was that ContinueWith is user-facing interface with a lot of null checks and other checks, while GetAwaiter is intended to be used by compiler (as MSDN says) and is very low level. In your Gist on my machine the first one is still faster by very meaningless amount. Need to run for a long time and do t-test :) I also use GetAwaiter directly in some places without `task{}` - it is convenient to use callbacks in some special cases.

Comment: I put up this as a suggestion to the FSharp lang design and quoted you there as well: https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/581

Comment: @dustinmoris in the end it was simpler to move all TPL stuff to a C# library